# xcodebuild archive with Skip Install

Tags: xcode4, xcodebuild

My XCode project contains subproject (static library). In this static library project's settings `Skip install` option is set to `YES`.

I want to make an archive of my project. At this moment I can do this with command `xcodebuild  -scheme MyScheme -sdk iphoneos6.0 archive`. But in scheme `MyScheme` I have `Release` configuration for `Archive` action. I want to be able to create archive in `Debug` configuration too.

Then I tried to use `xcodebuild -target MyTarget -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos6.0 archive` command, but it does not compute:

`=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET foo OF PROJECT fooProj WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
unsupported build action 'archive'`

I think I get this error because of `Skip install` option. Also, making archive and build with `target` and `configuration` are preferred rather than using `scheme` option, because schemes data is in `.gitignore` file and different developers may have different schemes for the same project.

Is there any methods to make an archive of my project with respect to `target` and `configuration` options?

Answer (score 0):

`xcodebuild -project TestBuildProject.xcodeproj -configuration Release -scheme TestBuildProject archive`

So, to archive your configuration has to be Release not Debug and you have to specify a scheme.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html